# How to build a class for all the for loops in main() (Just to reduce code in the main function)

Tags: c++, stdvector

For loop iterates through the vector and show all strings on the console successfully:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<string>stringVector;
    string newStringEntry;

    cin>>newStringEntry;
    stringVector.push_back(newStringEntry);

    cin>>newStringEntry;
    stringVector.push_back(newStringEntry);

    for (vector<string>::iterator i = stringVector.begin(); i != stringVector.end(); ++i) 
    {
        cout<<*i<<endl;
    }
}
```

But this makes the code hard to read (said our teacher) now we have to build a class for the for loop and the main should look like this after the change:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<string>stringVector;
    string newStringEntry;

    cin>>newStringEntry;
    stringVector.push_back(newStringEntry);

    cin>>newStringEntry;
    stringVector.push_back(newStringEntry);

    showStrings();
}
```

The problem I see is that I cannot just copy paste the for loop to an own class because
the vector name I declare in the main is not known in the class so I get an error.

How can I get this working?

My class so far looks like this:

```
class VectorHelp {
    void showStrings() const 
    {
        for (vector<string>::iterator i = vectorName.begin();
                i != vectorName.end();
                ++i)
        {
            cout << *i << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I doubt that the `main` loop is supposed to look as you’ve shown it after the chance since that simply doesn’t work. Furthermore, this doesn’t use any class at all.

Comment: Are you sure that function(showStrings) has to be parameterless?

Comment: This is a case of not understanding variable scope ... do you understand why stringVector isnt available outside main? what ways you could have to get it to your class?

Comment: Yes I do understand, stringVector is declared in the main and cannot be known in the VectorHelp.h class. So I have to pass the stringVector as parameter to the VectorHelp class method showStrings. Will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Your C++ teacher doesn't also teach Java, by any chance? In C++, functions don't need to be part of any class. There doesn't seem to me any benefit here from defining a class. Maybe the benefit will manifest later, when you put an `addString` function in your class as well as `showStrings`, and make `stringVector` a data member of the class rather than a variable in `main`. Once that's done, you could have `showStrings` take no parameters.

Comment: He also teach Java correct. Thanks for help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your `vector<strings>` as a *method parameter*:

```
VectorHelp::showStrings(stringVector);

...

static void showStrings(const vector<string>& stringVector)
```

Note that the name of your formal and actual parameter do not need to be the same. Also note that `showStrings` should be a class member function (i.e. `static`), not an instance member function.

Finally, note that printing without loops can be done using facilities of the standard C++ library:

```
ostream_iterator<string> out_it (cout, "\n");
copy (stringVector.begin(), stringVector.end(), out_it);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should store your vector in your class, or pass it to your function.

Comment: Pass it to the function is more what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you mean something like this:

```
class VectorHelp
{
    private:
         std::vector<std::string> stringVector

    public:

    void add(const string& str)
    {
        stringVector.push_back(str);
    }

    void printStrings()
    {
        for (vector<string>::iterator i = stringVector.begin(); i != stringVector.end(); i++)
        {
            cout << *i << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Not sure though if the for loop you provided is the correct one, I don't really use iterators and rather just use indexes.

But the above class is a class that you can instatiate and add strings to to print them out later!

Comment: Thanks Christian, this is very useful.